# What's the easiest way to validate a username / password in Treeline?

Tags: sails.js, treeline

I know this is a total novice question, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

So I'm creating my first app in Treeline and simply want to check to see if a username / password combination is valid.

What's the best way to do that given the current machines that are available? Attempted to use the Password machine with "Check Password" but wasn't immediately clear how you take the hashed password returned from "find user" and compare it to the hashed pw already stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ended up figuring this out after some trial and error.

Use the Find One User machine which will return the encrypted password. Then use the Check Password machine using your unencrypted password parameter as the first value, then the FindOneUser variable as the second.

[image]

If you click the FindOneUser bubble, it will turn into a dropdown and it will allow you to choose the password key from the dictionary.

[image]